How to call a function with clap
I want to call a function store_blocklist::insert_blocklist() by using clap
pub fn args() -> Command {
    Command::new("admin-cli")
        .about("CLI to manage admin tasks")
        .subcommand_required(true)
        .arg_required_else_help(true)
        .allow_external_subcommands(false)
        .subcommand(
            Command::new("blocklist")
                .about("Storing the blocklists of SteveBlack in the database")
                //call store_blocklist::insert_blocklist() here
        )
}

How can I do this?

I don't understand. Do you want to call the function if the argument is provided?

Yes, I want to do something like this: admin-cli --blocklist and this should call my function.

Then just parse arguments and see if --blocklist was passed. Have you red docs/tutorials in clap's documentation? It should have snippets, that provide this "functionality".

This is not the job of Clap. Clap is a command-line arguments parser, and that's it.
After Clap processes the user's arguments, you can do whatever you want with them, including calling your function:
use clap::{Arg, ArgAction, Command};

pub fn args() -> Command {
    Command::new("admin-cli")
        .about("CLI to manage admin tasks")
        .arg_required_else_help(true)
        .allow_external_subcommands(false)
        .arg(
            Arg::new("blocklist")
                .long("blocklist")
                .help("Storing the blocklists of SteveBlack in the database")
                .action(ArgAction::SetTrue),
        )
}

fn main() {
    let cmd = args();
    let args = cmd.get_matches();

    if args.get_flag("blocklist") {
        // Call your function here.
        println!("Hi from blocklist!");
    }
}

